# how to stop Firebase messaging from sending notifications? (IOS 10)

Tags: ios, firebase, ios10, firebase-cloud-messaging

I developing an IOS software which is connected to a server and receive FCM messages and working fine.

These messages are different from user to another user. that is every user has a unique set of messages.

My problem is when a user logout. I still receive the messages of previous user.

I tried to delete the token by the following code but it appears the token is not deleted when I printing it.

```
if FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() != nil {
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().deleteToken(withAuthorizedEntity: gcmSenderID, scope: kFIRInstanceIDScopeFirebaseMessaging, handler: { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
        } else {
            print("Token Deleted")
        }
    })}

    print(FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token())
```

Also I need to take a new token when another user login or register.